# Aggregate rows by identical column values for multiple data type columns

Tags: r, row, aggregate, multiple-columns, na

I am trying to aggregate rows with identical ObservationID for the following data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nd29kx2j7vik3tj/data.stackoverflow.question.25.11.2016.txt?dl=0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUPtb.jpg)

In the picture: >data is the original data, and at the top it shows how I would like to look my data like after aggregating

I tried:

```
data1<-aggregate( .~ ObservationID,data=data,FUN= paste)
```

which returns numbers instead of names for some of the columns, and places NA over a cell with an actual value (see picture)

and I tried:

```
data2<-aggregate(x=data,by=list(data$ObservationID),FUN = na.omit)
```

which returns two columns for every one column that wat put in.

On the top of the picture, I show how I would like to my data to be returned. Can someone help?

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.